# Concatenar duas strings sobrepondo suas substrings de intersecção

Tags: php

Como faço para inserir a string `listing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score`
 no final da string `http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&order=date`
soprepondo as substrings de interção entre as duas ficando da seguinte forma:
`http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score`

seguindo o mesmo raciocionio concatenar esta string `http://www.playnow3dgames.com/`
com esta outra `game.php?id=cyclomaniacs-epic` resultando em: 
`http://www.playnow3dgames.com/game.php?id=cyclomaniacs-epic`

a área da substring de interção deve ser somente entre o final da primeira e no inicio da segunda.
e como verificar se há uma area de intersecção (no final e no inicio) entre duas strings

Imagem descrevendo o processo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em vermelho a area de intersecção entre as duas strings a serem concatenadas, em verde o resultado.

Comment: O que determina  a mudança? é sempre o que virá depois do primeiro `.php` que for encontrado? Precisa achar um padrão para escolher o ponto da mudança.

Comment: @bigown, deverá ser da seguinte forma: a string inicial deve ser sempre a completa (http://....) e inserimos a segunda no final da primeira, note que o inicio da segunda coincide com o final da primeira então devemos remover esta parte semelhante da primeira ou da segunda e concatenarmos o final da segunda, note que quando não a semelhanças como no segundo exemplo não há o que remover

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Isso não contempla a concatenação de algumas strings

Comment: Acho que se colocasse o problema real a ser resolvido ficaria mais fácil aparecerem boas soluções. Até pelo fato da sobreposição de string não ser solução para mesclagem de parâmetros, parece haver uma confusão de conceitos na questão, que talvez para o autor tenha algum sentido, mas para quem lê pode gerar dúvidas (ou de repente nem ser a solução ideal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, honestamente, não sei qual utilidade de um processo desse tipo, seria mais fácil passar a nova URL pra função que carrega a nova página, não? mas enfim... criei a seguinte função `PHP`:

```
function alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNova){
    $url = strstr($urlNova,"?", true);
    $url = strstr($urlAntiga,$url, true).$url;
    $path = substr(reverse_strrchr($urlAntiga, "/"), 0);
    $aux = strstr($urlAntiga,"?", true);
    $aux2 = strstr($urlNova,"?", true);

    if($aux != "" && $aux != $url){
        $url = $path.$aux2;
    }

    $dadosNovo = strstr($urlNova,"?");

    if ($url == ""){
        $var1 = substr($urlAntiga, strlen($urlAntiga)- 1);
        $var2 = substr($urlAntiga, strlen($urlAntiga)- 1);

        if ($var1 == "/" && $var2 == "/") {
            $urlAntiga = substr($urlAntiga,0,-1);
        }elseif ($var1 == "/" && $var2 == "/"){
            $urlAntiga .= "/";
        }
        $url .= $urlAntiga.$urlNova;
    }else{
        if ($dadosNovo != ""){
            $url .= $dadosNovo;
        }
    }

return $url;
}
```

Utilizei também uma [função](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strrchr.php#39957) que achei na página oficial do `PHP`:

```
function reverse_strrchr($haystack, $needle){
    $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    if($pos === false){
        return $haystack;
    }
    return substr($haystack, 0, $pos + 1);
}
```

Realizei os seguintes testes com sucesso:

```
$urlAntiga = "http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&order=date";
$urlNovo = "listing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score";

echo alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNovo)."<br/><br/><br/>";

$urlAntiga = "http://www.playnow3dgames.com/testing.php?genre=sports&order=date";
$urlNovo = "listing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score";

echo alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNovo)."<br/><br/><br/>";

$urlAntiga = "http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&order=date";
$urlNovo = "testing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score";

echo alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNovo)."<br/><br/><br/>";

$urlAntiga = "http://www.playnow3dgames.com/";
$urlNovo = "http://www.playnow3dgames.com/game.php?id=cyclomaniacs-epic";

echo alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNovo)."<br/><br/><br/>";

$urlAntiga = "http://www.playnow3dgames.com/";
$urlNovo = "/new/16/";

echo alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNovo)."<br/><br/><br/>";

$urlAntiga = "MacacoChicleteBanana";
$urlNovo = "BananaLaranjaSorvete";

echo alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNovo)."<br/><br/><br/>";

$urlAntiga = "MacacoChicleteBanana";
$urlNovo = "UrsoCamelo";

echo alteraURL($urlAntiga, $urlNovo);
```

Obtive os seguintes resultados:

> ```
> http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score
>
>
> http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score
>
>
> http://www.playnow3dgames.com/testing.php?genre=sports&page=1&order=score
>
>
> http://www.playnow3dgames.com/game.php?id=cyclomaniacs-epic
>
>
> http://www.playnow3dgames.com/new/16/
>
>
> MacacoChicleteBananaBananaLaranjaSorvete
>
>
> MacacoChicleteBananaUrsoCamelo
> ```

Comment: esta função não funciona para o terceiro exemplo

Comment: Dá uma olha @RicardoHenrique vê se é isso mesmo que você precisa

Comment: ,@MarceloBonifazio não é bem isso, deve funcionar da seguinte forma: ao concatenar a primeira com a segunda deve-se atentar ao fato do final da primera ser semelhante ao inicio da segunda assim mantemos somente a umas das partes semelhantes e concatenamos(pode haver casos onde o final da primeira e o inicio da segunda são diferentes  logo nada deve ser feito), em sua resposta esta se trocando o valor mediante a posição da barra, eu coloquei alguns exemplos (imagem) na pergunta veja que os resultados (em verde) das strings são diferentes dos apresentados pela sua resposta